# Facebook Album Access in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

I want to access facebook album in my Swift Application. I have logged into the app. Then I call using Graph API to access the facebook Albums. The result is nil.

```
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": ""], httpMethod: "GET")?.start(completionHandler: {(connection , result, error) -> Void in

        if(error == nil){
            guard let dict = result as? [String:Any], let albums = dict["data"] as? [[String:Any]] else {

                return
            }
        }
    })
```

Can Anybody helped me access facebook Album in iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look in this part of code that gives you data from albums in **Swift** .

```
func getMyAlbums(){
                let connection = GraphRequestConnection()
                connection.add(GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/albums?fields=cover_photo,picture,name,count")) { httpResponse, result in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let response):
                        self.parseAlbums(response: response)
                    case .failed(let error):
                        print("Graph Request Failed: \(error)")
                    }
                }
                connection.start()
            }

    func parseAlbums(response: GraphRequest.Response){
                guard let responseDictionary = response.dictionaryValue else {
                    return
                }
                guard let data: NSArray = responseDictionary["data"] as? NSArray else {
                    return
                }

                for  index in 0..<data.count {
                    let valueDict : NSDictionary = data[index] as! NSDictionary
                    let id = valueDict.object(forKey: "id") as! String
                    let count = valueDict.object(forKey: "count") as! NSNumber
                    let name = valueDict.object(forKey: "name") as! String
                    let pictureUrl = ((valueDict.object(forKey: "picture") as! NSDictionary)
                        .object(forKey: "data") as! NSDictionary)
                        .object(forKey: "url") as! String
                    let album = Album(id:id,name:name,coverUrl:pictureUrl,countImages:Int(count))
                    albums.append(album)
                }
                albums = albums.sorted(by: {$0.name < $1.name})
}
```

you can alsi check my project on extracting pictures from facebook : 
[Facebook Photos Extracting App](https://github.com/SafoineMoncefAmine/FaceBook-Photos-Exporting-App/blob/master/FaceBook%20Photos%20Exporting%20App/FaceBook%20Photos%20Exporting%20App/views/controllers/AlbumsViewController.swift)